# Best way to lighten only shadows?

Tags: lighting, displacement, shadows, height-map

I have a simple scene (in Blender 3.0):

[image]
[image]

in which I have a problem with shadows. The texture of the topographic map will go on this relief. So I need the shadows to be lighter - maybe something like this but even lighter (something like "natural outside lighting and shadow"):

[image]

I tried the settings in world properties (enlarge sun size) but it affected the size of my shadows (I tried also combine it with changing the shading offset). Then I tried fast GI Approximation, adding another light source on the opposite site of my main lighting ... but this options faded my whole scene.

There is some way to affect only the shadows? It is really necessary for me to make the map legible even in places with shadows. **Thank you** for any advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can adjust contrast and exposure easily in the final render.
And you can also use Curves to fine-tune the shadows.

[image]